# Why does my python script continue while if __name__==__main__ runs?

Tags: python, if-statement, multiprocessing

Below is a simplified version of a problem I'm facing. When I run my code, example below, why does the script run code below the if _name__==__main_ section while the function which sits underneath the if statement is still running? I thought the p_1.join() command should block the script from continuing until the separate process has finished. In the output below I'm expecting the word "Finished" to only be printed when all of the script has concluded - but instead it is being printed second and then last.

In the past I have used poolexecutor for similar problems; but in this project I need to start each process individually so that I can assigned separate independent functions to each process.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def a(x,q):
    time.sleep(3)
    q.put(x*x)

q=Queue()
def main():
    print("Main Function Starts")
    p_1 = Process(target=a, args=(5,q))
    p_1.start()
    p_1.join()
    b= q.get()
    print(b)
    print("Main Function Ends")

if __name__ == '__main__':        
       main()

print("Finished")

**Output:**
Main Function Starts
Finished
25
Main Function Ends
Finished
```

Comment: That code was supposed to go *in* the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. That's the point of `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: I ran the included Python code and could not replicate the issue or output, as the `Finished` is not printed before `25`.

Answer (score 4):

You were supposed to put that code *in* the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. Preventing this kind of thing is the whole point of `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

You're on Windows. When you start `p_1`, `multiprocessing` launches a separate Python process, and one of the first things that process does is *import* your file as a module. When it does that, the module's `__name__` isn't `'__main__'`, so anything inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard doesn't run, but `print("Finished")` is outside the guard.

Your program isn't somehow continuing past `main()` while `main()` is still running. The worker process is performing the unwanted print.

Comment: Thanks so much. Totally resolved the issues and very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your script? When I ran your script on command line, 'Finished' was printed once like below.

```
$ python test.py

Main Function Starts
25
Main Function Ends
Finished
```